# References for learning about acid and bases in organic chemistry

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, reference-request, books

Can someone help me find references to help solve [these problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD2nb.jpg). These are problems suggested by my instructor.

I'm specifically interested in learning how to solve question A.(b). How can I know whether a reaction will occur between the two products and further, how can I predict what the product will be if a reaction does occur (what atoms bond together, and how can I know which atoms bond together in any organic reaction)?

Answer (score 3):

Concerning your first question: I found that the  book ["Organic Chemistry" by Clayden, Warren, Wothers and Greeves](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199270295) and here especially the 8th chapter contains a very good and readable introduction to acidity and basicity. After you have worked through this chapter you should be able to explain why certain molecules are as basic/acidic as they are and you see a lot of typical $\mathrm{p}K_{\mathrm{a}}$ values for a lot of substance classes so that you get some knowledge about what $\mathrm{p}K_{\mathrm{a}}$ values you can expect for other substances. As for your second question: If you want to know why reactions occur in the way they do you'll have to take courses in Organic Chemistry. Apart from that, I wholeheartedly recommend the aforementioned book again. If you work through this book (this will take you a while: it has 1200 pages... but then again, that is 1200 very readable pages :)) you'll have a very solid basis in organic reaction mechanisms and organic chemistry in general. If you want to dig a little deeper [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0121381102) book by Bruckner is very thorough but a little dry.

One particular perspective that I found very helpful in explaining why reactions happen in the way they do was the frontier orbital theory. A very good and readable book about its use in organic chemistry is [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470746599) one by Fleming. The book by Clayden et al. also uses this theory a lot in explaining reaction mechanisms.

Comment: +1, I echo your sentiments re: the Clayden, et al. and (especially) Fleming books. The latter is really excellent in dealing with an intrinsically abstruse subject. On the introductory level, I think Klein's _Organic Chemistry_ is also fairly good, though a bit handwavy w/r/t certain complexities, and with disappointingly meager coverage of MO theory. At a higher level, I thought Carey & Sundberg's two-volume _Advanced Organic Chemistry_ was highly instructive and lucid.